# Package decleration on manifest file

Tags: android, android-facebook

My app have 6 packges:

```
com.example.personalassistant
com.example.personalassistant.a
com.example.personalassistant.b
com.example.personalassistant.c
com.example.personalassistant.d (hold the start Activity)
com.myassistant.utills
com.personalassistant.db_handling
```

My question is how should i declare the "packge" in my android manifest?

I am running into trouble when trying to integrate my app with Facebook based on my app hash and i was thinking waybe its beascuse my packge is not declared properly.

Comment: declare `com.example.personalassistant` as your package.

Comment: com.example.personalassistant should contains your activities?

Comment: When you have created your application at time when you have given package name then set that package to your manifest file as a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be confusing package name with your activity names. Or you have a lot of classes spread among multiple packages.

In any case, you'll usually want the package name in your manifest to match the one in the package statement at the top of your startup activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as you package name. com.example.personalassistant.d (hold the start Activity).
Please make sure to give the package name where the all you activities are contained.